# Сложность в отправке пост запроса REACT

Tags: reactjs, node.js

Есть функция которая кидает пост запрос:

```js
let deleteInfo = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/deleteWorker" , { workerid })
    .then((response) => {
        if (response.data) {
          console.log(response.data)
          console.log("есть")
        } else {
          console.log("нет")
        }
      })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

На серверной части я пытаюсь ее обработать

```js
app.post("/deleteWorker", (req, res) => {
  let workerid = req.body.workerid
  res.send({ message: "что-то" })
})
```

Однако я не понимаю почему post запрос завершается с ошибкой 404.

Слушаю порт:

```
app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("was connected")
})
```

Ответ который приходит:

```
{
    "message": "Request failed with status code 404",
    "name": "AxiosError",
    "stack": "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404\n    at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48666:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:47374:66)",
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "adapter": [
            "xhr",
            "http"
        ],
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "env": {},
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "method": "post",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080/deleteWorker",
        "data": "{\"workerid\":2}"
    },
    "code": "ERR_BAD_REQUEST",
    "status": 404
}
```

Comment: Может порт не тот?

Comment: @SwaD да вроде тот

Comment: Сама ошибка однозначная, страница не найдена. Попробуйте руками ввести в браузере `http://localhost:8080/deleteWorker` и посмотреть, что произойдет

Comment: @SwaD Cannot GET /deleteWorker

Comment: ¯\\(ツ)/¯ Посмотрите в отладчике, куда отправляется запрос. Попробуйте, для эксперимента, переделать на бэке запрос на GET. По какой то причине, нода не видит путь /deleteWorker . Помню, был случай, написал новый энд поинт, а ноду с изменениями не ребутнул... Поставьте внутрь app.post вывод консоли, может ломается из-за отсутствия каких то заголовков...

Comment: Ну приложите скрин шот что ли... Еще варианты: передавть не `{ workerid }` а в явном виде `{ workerid: workerid }`. Попробуйте добавить заголовки в запрос. Доступные опции [указаны тут](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#axios-api)

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю в чем была проблема, надо было пару раз перезагрузить локалку, прежде чем посыпались другие ошибки. Проблема решена.